# Get alias type for value types C#

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm trying to get things like `bool` instead of `Boolean` and `int` instead of `Int32`. Is there any way out of the box that reflection gives that option when querying for the type name of a certain property or do I have to do my own mapping? To get the name I'm using `myPropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name`

Thanks!

Comment: No, the language-agnostic reflection methods do not return language-specific names. But it's easy to create a language-specific method outside of plain reflection.

Comment: that's what I thought. Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: For reference to others looking for a quick answer, you can use `CSharpCodeProvider` (exists in .NET Core 2 as well) to get "int" or "string" instead of the full CLR Type names.